# Error moving JSP file into WEB-INF directory with Stripes

Tags: java, web-applications, stripes, web-inf

I have the following Stripes ActionBean:

```
package myapp;

import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.*;

public class WelcomeActionBean extends MyAppActionBean {
    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution view() {
        return new ForwardResolution("/welcome.jsp");
    }
}
```

When I load /myapp/Welcome.action in a browser, the contents of welcome.jsp are displayed.

However, when I move welcome.jsp to /WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp and change the ForwardResolution argument to reflect that change, i.e.:

```
return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp");
```

I get the following error when I load /myapp/Welcome.action:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.ActionBeanNotFoundException: Could not locate an ActionBean that is bound to the URL [/Welcome.action]. Commons reasons for this include mis-matched URLs and forgetting to implement ActionBean in your class. Registered ActionBeans are: {/controller/DefaultView.action=class net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DefaultViewActionBean, /myapp/MyApp.action/=class myapp.MyAppActionBean, /myapp/Welcome.action/=class myapp.WelcomeActionBean, /controller/DefaultView.action/=class net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DefaultViewActionBean, /myapp/MyApp.action=class myapp.MyAppActionBean, /myapp/Welcome.action=class myapp.WelcomeActionBean}
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.AnnotatedClassActionResolver.getActionBean(AnnotatedClassActionResolver.java:341)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.NameBasedActionResolver.getActionBean(NameBasedActionResolver.java:264)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.AnnotatedClassActionResolver.getActionBean(AnnotatedClassActionResolver.java:293)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper$1.intercept(DispatcherHelper.java:106)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:158)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.intercept(BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.java:113)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.wrap(ExecutionContext.java:74)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.resolveActionBean(DispatcherHelper.java:102)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.resolveActionBean(DispatcherServlet.java:238)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:141)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:247)
```

Is it necessary to perform any special configuration in order to store JSP files in the WEB-INF directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is the following: your `WelcomeActionBean` in not in a package ([web, www, stripes, action]) automagically handled by the [`NameBasedActionResolver`](http://javadox.com/net.sourceforge.stripes/stripes/1.5.7/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/NameBasedActionResolver.html) (read the javadoc) so it is actually mapped to `/myapp/Welcome.action` (as stated in the error message).

So, when you request `/Welcome.action`, there isn't any existing `ActionBean` bound to that URL and the resolver fallbacks to `/welcome.jsp` (again, see the  [`NameBasedActionResolver`](http://javadox.com/net.sourceforge.stripes/stripes/1.5.7/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/NameBasedActionResolver.html) javadoc). And when you move your JSP under `/WEB-INF/jsp`, well, you run out of luck and everything just fails.

To solve this, either:

- Access the "right" (in the current state) URL binding i.e. `/myapp/Welcome.action`
- Or, if you want your ActionBean to be bound to `/Welcome.action` by the conventions, move it in a package handled by the [`NameBasedActionResolver`](http://javadox.com/net.sourceforge.stripes/stripes/1.5.7/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/NameBasedActionResolver.html), e.g. `action`:

  ```
  package myapp.action;

  import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.*;

  public class WelcomeActionBean extends MyAppActionBean {
      @DefaultHandler
      public Resolution view() {
          return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp");
      }
  }
  ```
- Or add a `@UrlBinding` to your action to configure the binding explicitly:

  ```
  package myapp;

  import net.sourceforge.stripes.action.*;

  @UrlBinding("/Welcome.action")
  public class WelcomeActionBean extends MyAppActionBean {
      @DefaultHandler
      public Resolution view() {
          return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Your tip about NameBasedActionResolver pushed me in the right direction.  I was accessing /myapp/Welcome.action instead of /myapp/myapp/Welcome.action.

Answer (score -1):

`WEB-INF` is a special directory, and its contents aren't accessible to the client. (It makes sense - you wouldn't want the client to be able to download your `web.xml` or your `.class` files.)

You need to move the JSP files outside of `WEB-INF`.

Comment: the client isn't accessing these jsps. The server is, using internal forward. It is perfectly OK to have jsps in the `WEB-INF` folder, if they are included or forwarded to